# Geometry nodes, how to rotate a face?

Tags: geometry-nodes

this grid is a combination of doors and windows.
is there a way to **rotate** these **faces** similar to the picture below?

[image]

[image]

001
[image]

002
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You will need to select each face by Index, offset it's center and then rotate it using set position node. Here is an example only for one face. [image]

------------------------------------------------------
**UPD**

[image]

------------------------------------------------------
**UPD2**

When you have an ngon (polygon with more than 4 verts) it's not that simple to find it's center. So ther workaround here looks like this. 
**First,you can calculate the center of each face using node setup from this thread:** [Geometry Nodes. Find the center of a rectangle whether or not there are multiple vertices on one side](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279576/geometry-nodes-find-the-center-of-a-rectangle-whether-or-not-there-are-multiple)
Second, you need to calculate the size of the face along Y axis.
Third, you need to substract half of the size of the face from it's position along Y axis and then you can rotate. 
Hope this helps.[image] 
 
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried it, and it creates a small gap between the rotated face and the others. also, it seems that it doesn't work on different forms of faces. (I uploaded the blend file )

Comment: Use split edges and capture attrubute instead of separate geometry. Then it will work correctly. I added blend file to my answer. Take a look.

Comment: gap still there.

Comment: Updated blend file, shouldn't be any gap now

Comment: thank u, well done

Comment: for some reason, faces with indexes of 0 and 7 don't rotate properly (gap)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the update.